# C programming: Type char variable Is For Just One Letter Or Number?

Tags: c, variables, unix, syntax

In the textbook "The C Programming Language," page 9 has the line below.

"char character--a single byte"

Is this meaning the type "char" variable can keep just one letter, number or symbol?

I also want to understand the term's precise definition.

My understanding is here. Is this correct?

---

Character: Any letter, number or symbol.

Character string: Several characters.

---

If it is wrong, I want the correct definition.

Thank you, all members of the community for everyday's support.

Comment: One `char` is for values from `-128` to `127` and you typically think of [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/) when you think of printable characters (which includes digits) Only the first 7 bytes are used for ASCII (you will hear the term 7-bit ASCII) **Note:** `char` is not *signed* on all implementations so on those where `char` is unsigned, you have `0` to `255`.

Comment: A character string is a sequence of characters terminated by `'\0'` (the *nul-character* - ASCII `0`) That is how functions that operate on character strings know where the string ends (you will here the term *nul-terminated string*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formal C standard definition of character sets (5.2.1):

> Two sets of characters and their associated collating sequences shall be defined: the set in which source files are written (*the source character set*), and the set interpreted in the execution environment (*the execution character set*). Each set is further divided into a *basic character set*, whose contents are given by this subclause, and a set of zero or more locale-specific members (which are not members of the basic character set) called extended characters. The combined set is also called the *extended character set*. The values of the members of the execution character set are implementation-defined.

The *basic character set* is specified to contain:

> - the 26 uppercase letters of the Latin alphabet /--/
> - the 26 lowercase letters of the Latin alphabet /--/
> - the 10 decimal digits /--/
> - the following 29 graphic characters
>
>   ```
>   ! " # % & ' ( ) * + , - . / :
>   ; < = > ? [ \ ] ^ _ { | } ~
>   ```
> - the space character, and control characters representing horizontal tab, vertical tab, and form feed.
> - In the basic execution character set, there shall be
>   control characters representing alert, backspace, carriage return, and new line.

> The representation of each member of the source and execution basic
> character sets shall fit in a byte.

Then 6.2.5 says:

> An object declared as type `char` is large enough to store any member of the basic execution character set.

The formal definition of a byte is very similar (3.6):

> **byte**
> addressable unit of data storage large enough to hold any member of the basic character set of the execution environment

Furthermore, it is specified that a `char` is always 1 byte large (6.5.3.4):

> The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand /--/
> When sizeof is applied to an operand that has type `char`, `unsigned char`, or
> `signed char`, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1.

The C standard does not however specify the number of bits in a byte, only that it has to be 8 bits or more.

Comment: Your bulleted list helps me understand what the character is. Thank you! Although I have practiced Bash Shell Scripts, C programming seems to require more precise writting.

Answer (score 1):

The standard (draft n1570 for C11) says:

> An object declared as type char is large enough to store any member of the basic
> execution character set. If a member of the basic execution character set is stored in a
> char object, its value is guaranteed to be nonnegative.

As the standard character set contains all upper and lower case alphabets, decimal digits and some other characters, it needs at least 7 bits to be represented. Anyway the standard mandates the size of a char to be at least 8 bits:

> [The] implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign.
> — number of bits for smallest object that is not a bit-field (byte)
> CHAR_BIT 8

A char must be individually addressable. For that reason a char is said to be a byte, and *by definition* `sizeof(char)` is 1 whatever the exact number of bits - some old mainframes used 12 or 16 bits characters.

`unsigned char` and `signed char` are integer types that use same storage size as `char`. They are distinct types, yet the conversions between the 3 types are perfectly defined and never change the representation. Even if a distinct type, the standard requires:

> The implementation shall define char to have the same range,
> representation, and behavior as either signed char or unsigned char.

On common architectures, a `char` uses 8 bits. All values in range 0-127 represent the ASCII character set (NB: this is **not** mandated by the standard, and other representation like EBCDIC were used). Values in the other range (-128 to -1 or 128-255) are called the extended chars and can represent either a ISO-8859-x (or Latin) charset, or bytes in a multi-byte character set like UTF-8 or UCS2 (subset of UTF16 for unicode characters in the 0-FFFF range). ISO-8859-1 or Latin1 is a single byte charset representing Unicode characters in the range à-255. It used to be a de facto standard and Windows still uses CP1252 (a close variation) for west european language system

TL/DR: to directly answer your question:

- a char represents *some* symbols, at least the basic execution character set
- a character string is *by convention* a null terminated char array. The represented symbols depend on the used charset, and for multi-byte charsets (like UTF8) there is no 1 to 1 relation between a char and a symbol

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: I should have read the *limits* part before writing that. Edited now... Thanks for the head up.

Answer (score 0):

Typically `char` is a one-byte sized variable type, and as byte is made of 8 bits, the value range for char is 0-255 or -128-127 if signed (One bit is used for sign indication).

Those 255 options, are used to represent a value, in the case of a `char`, a symbol, letter or digit (or some special characters). from the ASCII codec.

If you want for example to store a Japanese letter or an emoji, which requires 2 bytes (As there are much more characters than 255 as you know). You will have to use a type that support such size - for unicode such as `wchar_t`

Comment: *typically* 8 bits, *typically* 0-255 or -128-127... but better than dash-o's answer which just ignored majority of all consumer computing devices in existence...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Correct, Added typically ;)

Answer (score 0):

The 'char' take one byte of storage, and can represent a value between -128 to +127. This is commonly used to hold single ASCII character. In the ASCII encoding, all printable characters are assigned values between 32 (space) to 126 (tilde, '~'), with non printable characters assigned to the rest of the codes.

Note that unlike the Java char (which can bold any unicode character), the "c" char will not be able to represent the latin characters.

Comment: The C standard does not say that the range of char is `-128` to `+127`, though it is a *possibility*.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala A `char` can always hold the values between `-128` to `127` and an `unsigned char` can hold values between `0` to `255` and that's the certainty

Comment: @Lucas **incorrect**. A char can always hold values between `0` and `127`. You need to get yourself a Raspberry PI.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I'm really gonna get that. ;) But before that you need to explain.

Comment: @Lucas https://godbolt.org/z/3ze5WY - the range of `char` and signedness of it is implementation-defined. It so happened that Intel compilers decided that it was signed. ARM decided otherwise. https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=18269886

Comment: Oh, that's why I'm getting a printable `a like` character when I'm doing, `char a = -125` and `putchar(a)`

Comment: @Lucas that is a completely different thing. `putchar` takes in an `int` and converts it to `unsigned char`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala However isn't your one comment _"incorrect. A char can..."_ conflicting with the other _"...of it is implementation-defined...."_. If it is implementation-defined, then how can you say that I'm incorrect. Because I'm using `intel` and it worked for me.